# How to build responsive Accordion Tabs without duplicated tab content in TailwindCSS & Alpine.js?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to build an Accordion Tabs component in TailwindCSS & Alpine.js, similar to [A11y Accordion Tabs](https://matthiasott.github.io/a11y-accordion-tabs/).

In mobile viewports, the component should behave like an Accordion.
On desktop, it should behave like Tabs.

But how to avoid duplicating the same content in the page?  Ideally the content inside the tab/accordion should be only in the page once so that the HTML isn't bloated.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/anthonymf/pen/xxLRxqb?editors=1000) and here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="m-1.5" x-data="{ tab : 'tab-a' }">
  <div class="sm:flex">
    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-a'">
      <div :class="tab === 'tab-a' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="sm:rounded-t-sm sm:mr-2 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-1.5 pb-3 pt-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0 w-full sm:w-max">
        Tab A
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="sm:hidden relative overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300" x-ref="containerA" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-a' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerA.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
      Tab A content
    </div>

    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-b'">
      <div :class="tab === 'tab-b' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="sm:rounded-t-sm sm:mr-2 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-1.5 pb-3 pt-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0 w-full sm:w-max">
        Tab B
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="sm:hidden relative overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300" x-ref="containerB" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-b' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerB.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
      Tab B content
    </div>

    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-c'">
      <div :class="tab === 'tab-c' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="sm:rounded-t-sm sm:mr-2 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-1.5 pb-3 pt-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0 w-full sm:w-max">
        Tab C
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="sm:hidden relative overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300" x-ref="containerC" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-c' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerC.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
      Tab C content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden sm:block">
    <div x-show="tab === 'tab-a'">
      Tab A content should not be duplicated here
    </div>
    <div x-show="tab === 'tab-b'">
      Tab B content should not be duplicated here
    </div>
    <div x-show="tab === 'tab-c'">
      Tab C content should not be duplicated here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is to duplicate the tab headings instead of the content:

```
<div class="m-1.5" x-data="{ tab : 'tab-a' }">
  <div class="flex">
    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-a'">
      <h3 :class="tab === 'tab-a' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="hidden sm:block cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs w-16 border-2 border-b-0">
        Tab A
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-b'">
      <h3 :class="tab === 'tab-b' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="hidden sm:block cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs w-16 border-2 border-b-0">
        Tab B
      </h3>
    </a>
    <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-c'">
      <h3 :class="tab === 'tab-c' ? 'sm:bg-white' : 'sm:bg-gray-200'" class="hidden sm:block cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs w-16 border-2 border-b-0">
        Tab C
      </h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-a'">
    <h3 class="sm:hidden cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0">
      Tab A
    </h3>
  </a>
  <div class="overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300 sm:transition-none" x-ref="containerA" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-a' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerA.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
    Tab A content
  </div>
  <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-b'">
    <h3 class="sm:hidden cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0">
      Tab B
    </h3>
  </a>
  <div class="overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300 sm:transition-none" x-ref="containerB" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-b' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerB.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
    Tab B content
  </div>
  <a x-on:click="tab = 'tab-c'">
    <h3 class="sm:hidden cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 font-bold p-3 text-gray-700 text-xs my-px sm:mb-0">
      Tab C
    </h3>
  </a>
  <div class="overflow-hidden max-h-0 duration-300 sm:transition-none" x-ref="containerC" x-bind:style="tab === 'tab-c' ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.containerC.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
    Tab C content
  </div>
</div>
```